# how to get s3 object key by object url when I use aws lambda python?or How to get object by url?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I use python boto3
when I upload file to s3,aws lambda will move the file to other bucket,I can get object url by lambda event,like
`https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/diamond+white.side.jpg`

The object key is `xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/diamond+white.side.jpg` 
This is a simple example,I can replace "+" get object key, there are other complicated situations,I need to get object key by object url,How can I do it?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `urllib.parse.unquote` and then replace `+` with space.

From my knowledge, `+` is the only exception from URL parsing, so you should be safe if you do that by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
url_data = "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxxx/diamond+white.side.jpg".split("/")[3:]
object_key = "/".join(url_data)
```